# Обмен данными между двумя разными приложениями

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

Данные будут отправляться каждую секунду, а то и чаще.

Думал сделать методом отправки Broadcast. 
Каждую секунду будет происходить отправка 3х разных Broadcast сообщений.

Система будет работать так:
Приложение А запускает сервис который работает в фоне и постоянно генерирует события(если не вырубить вручную).

Примерное содержимое:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("action");
intent.putExtra("data", new int[]{666, 777, 88});
intent.putExtra("limit", new int[]{1, 2, 33});
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Приложение Б, должно принять и как то среагировать на эти сообщения..

мои опасения:
ANR - Broadcast принимает сообщения в UI потоке. (но как понял, можно и в другой поток перевести).

Хорошая ли это идея? Или есть еще другие камни о которых я не знаю?
Может стоит сделать по другому, как?

Comment: Для хорошего совета недостаточно информации. Что за события и кто их генерирует - постоянно работающий сервис или периодически запускающийся? События должны рассылаться любым приложениям или конкретному? В общем опишите словами логику взаимодействия, как это должно работать.

Comment: дополнил свой вопрос

Comment: Ресивер не ждёт события, его **вызывают** по событию. ANR можно выхватить только если в нём самом вы будете делать что-то долго-тяжёлое. Варианта два мне видится. Если приложение Б должно реагировать на события не зависимо от его видимости на экране, то без Broadcast не обойтись. При этом желательно посылать явный интент (с указанием пакета и класса ресивера), если задача передавать их конкретному приложению, а не всем желающим. Если же Б должно принимать посылки только в активном режиме, то читайте про [привязку к службе](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services?hl=ru)